# マクロを用いて行列を計算

Tags: c

マクロM，Nを定義して、M✕N行列の和と差を計算するプログラムを作成したいです。

マクロ関数ははじめに `define` で定義することは知っていますが、それからmain関数にどのようなことを書けばいいのかがわかりません。恐らく `for` 文の中身が変わると考えているのですが、
`i<2` や `j<3` の箇所を `i＜M`, `j＜N` のように変えるだけでいいのでしょうか。

実行例としては、下のようになればOKです。

**実行例** (3×2行列)

```
$ ./a.out
A?
(1, 1)成分? 1
(1, 2)成分? 2
(2, 1)成分? 3
(2, 2)成分? 4
(3, 1)成分? 5
(3, 2)成分? 6
B?
(1, 1)成分? 6
(1, 2)成分? 3
(2, 1)成分? 4
(2, 2)成分? 5
(3, 1)成分? 1
(3, 2)成分? 2
A=
  1   2 
  3   4 
  5   6 
B=
  6   3 
  4   5 
  1   2 
A+B=
  7   5 
  7   9 
  6   8 
A-B=
 -5  -1 
 -1  -1 
  4   4 
$
```

マクロを使わずに行列演算するプログラムを示します。

```
int main(void)
{
    /*2✕3の行列*/
    int ma[2][3],mb[2][3],mc[2][3];
    int i,j;
    /*行列A*/
    printf("A?\n");

    for(i=0;i<2;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++) {
            printf("(%d,%d)成分?", i+1, j+1);
            scanf("%d",&ma[i][j]);
        }
    }

    /*行列B*/
    printf("B?\n");
    for(i=0;i<2;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++) {
            printf("(%d,%d)成分?", i+1, j+1);
            scanf("%d",&mb[i][j]);
        }
    }

   /*A*/
    printf("A= \n");
    for(i=0;i<2;i++) {
            for(j=0;j<3;j++) {
    printf("%3d", ma[i][j]);

   }printf("\n");
  }

  /*B*/
    printf("B= \n");
    for(i=0;i<2;i++) {
            for(j=0;j<3;j++) {
    printf("%3d", mb[i][j]);

   }printf("\n");
  }
   /*A+B*/
    printf("A+B= \n");
    for(i=0;i<2;i++) {
            for(j=0;j<3;j++) {
    printf("%3d", ma[i][j] + mb[i][j]);

   }printf("\n");
  }

   /*A-B*/
     printf("A-B= \n");
     for(i=0;i<2;i++) {
            for(j=0;j<3;j++) {
    printf("%3d", ma[i][j] - mb[i][j]);          
   }printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: 質問のタイトルや冒頭にある「マクロ」は、この課題に対してあまり本質的な問題点とは思えないので、あなたがこの問題の何を難しいと思っているのかがよくわかりません。「マクロ」を使う必要がなければ、あなたはこのようなコードが書けるのでしょうか? それとも「行列の和と差を計算する」コードがそもそも書けないのでしょうか。なお、あなたは短い期間に多数の質問をしておいて、問題が解決できたのかどうかも、様々なコメントに対する返信も十分しておられないようです。その辺を放置し続けたせいで、自分の質問の意図をうまく伝えるテクニックを磨くことができていないように思われます。新しい質問を書く前に、過去に立ち戻って、解決できたかどうかを報告され、まだ解決できないのであれば新しいアドバイスをもらえるようコメントするなり、ご質問を編集するなりされることをお勧めしておきます。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。これからは解決の報告も含め、自分も返信をもっと丁寧にしようと思います。質問として意図していることは、「マクロ」を使わなければ行列コードを書くことはできるのですが、学校課題の指定は「マクロ」を使ってプログラムを書くということです。ですが、「マクロ」は　初めて聞いた内容であり、まず何から書き始めればいいのかもわかりませんでした。なので、マクロを使ったプログラムの方法を知りたいです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。過去質問の「承認」は今からでもできますし、コメントも今からでもつけられますので早速実践していただくと良いでしょう。『「マクロ」を使わなければ行列コードを書くことはできる』と言うのであれば、是非そのコードをお示し下さい。過去質問まで読み返せば、あなたがある程度コードを自分で書けるのは理解できますが、そうでなければ「こんな動きをするコードが欲しい」と言う丸投げ型の質問に見え、このサイトでは好まれない質問のスタイルになっています。

Comment: マクロを使わずに行列を計算するプログラムを示しました。また、質問の承認はどのようにすればよいのでしょうか。承認の仕方を探しては見たのですが、見当たらなかったので教えていただければ幸いです。いろいろすいません。

Comment: 質問の承認についてはこちらのヘルプを参照してください。 - [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。上記のへルプを参照しました。質問内容を読み返したところ自分の質問はこのサイトには適さない質問と思えたので、編集していこうと思います。

Comment: 結局、過去の質問は何一つ解決していないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

学校の課題を解かれているということで、「マクロを用いた」行列の計算が最終的に何を求めているのかは出題者にしか分からないのですが、期待する実行結果等から察するに(ご自身でも質問中に追記された通り)
「行列のサイズ M, N をそれぞれ `define` で定義する」でよいのではないでしょうか。

---

プログラムの実行時にユーザーが入力するのは "要素の値" のみで、行列のサイズは固定のようです。
サイズが同じ2つの行列 A,B で入力の受け付けと、結果の出力等で繰り返し行列のサイズを参照する必要が出てきますが、後からこの行列のサイズを変えたくなった時に、既存のマクロを使わないプログラムでは個々の `for` ループをすべて修正しなければいけません。

このような場合に `define` を用いて行列のサイズを **定数** として定義しておけば、プログラムの修正が最小限で済みます。

また、`for` ループの定義部分で `i<2` のように数字を直接指定してしまうと、後から見返した時にその数字が何を表しているのかが分かりづらくなります。(いわゆる [マジックナンバー](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9E%E3%82%B8%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%83%8A%E3%83%B3%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC_%28%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A0%29) 等と呼ばれます)

定数として "意味のある" 名前を割り当てておく事で、他人がそのプログラムを見たときでも内容を把握しやすくなります。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。M，Nの値を変えることによりさまざまな行列演算ができるプログラムを作るということが目的なので、cubickさんの推測で問題ないです。実践してみた結果、きちんと計算できていたので良かったです。